# Why is this data type conversion failing but not failing?

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes, type-conversion

Ok, so I'm wracking my brain on this one...

These two queries... though they appear the same... are apparently different in some fashion. When run against a database in SQL Server Management Studio the top one results in an error (Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.) where as the bottom one runs just fine. Any ideas as to why that would be?

```
SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'459B621C-A49A-49Cl-900F-AB14D61841E2');
SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'459B621C-A49A-49C1-900F-AB14D61841E2');
```

Could it be a character encoding issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference. The first one uses an `l`, the second is `1`.

Comment: Yep, that'd be it. Someone must have hand-typed something they shouldn't have... I'll blame our marketing dept... Thanks!

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables +1 for an awesome username!